# How to match the impedance of this antenna to a hybrid coupler

Tags: antenna

This's a differentially fed bow-tie antenna.

Can I feed each half of the bow-tie with a 50 ohms unbalanced coax feed line and connect these two coax lines with a 180 degree hybrid coupler whose impedance is 50 ohms?

[image]

Comment: Data sheets for the antenna and hybrid coupler please. Or, why not use a simple balun.

Comment: @Andyaka I just used a google image of differentially fed bow-tie structure. There is no antenna and hybrid coupler. I've been just wondering that what if I feed the elements separately like a monopole antenna with 50 ohm unbalanced lines, will this be balanced with a 180 degree hybrid coupler.

Comment: That should work. Tie the two coax shields together and earth them (might work unearthed if they are just only bonded to each other). Feed into the coupler to get A-B output. That's what I'd do.

Comment: @Andyaka why bond to each other rather than separately earthed?

Comment: How to match?  Huh? What is the impedance of that antenna?

Comment: @antfellow the most important thing is that the bonded coax screens are effectively equally connected to an earth (or might work when floating too).

Comment: @Andyaka reference impedance at the input of the hybrid is 50 ohm, so does its outputs. if I use 50 ohm coaxial unbalanced lines directly feeds one half of the antenna, should it work? (imagine that each half will be shaped for the matching by slots etc.) or will it need 100 ohm at the antenna feed point.

Comment: It all depends on the antenna output impedance.